# Flagging summary

Tags: support, flags, flag-history

What is the number that I see in brackets for the question that was flagged by me and accepted as an flag.

Eg: [Android Beginner [closed] **(5)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896760/android-beginner)

In the above question I can see a number (5). -What's this actually?

Another Example: [OutOfMemoryError when opening lot of little pictures [closed] **(3)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909128/outofmemoryerror-when-opening-lot-of-little-pictures)

What is this (3) ?

Comment: Like 99% of the hidden features here, just hover your mouse over the mysterious thing. In this case, hovering over the number in brackets will give "5 answers" and "3 answers" accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers represent the total number of answers posted under that question. It appears only for questions.

Click on the questions that you provided, you will notice that they have 5 and 3 answers respectively.